# Tapestry 5.4: how to use an external dist package?

Tags: swagger-ui, tapestry

I'd like to use the dist package from swagger-ui to be able to expose my webservice. The dist pkg is located here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist

While I can use this: [Swagger UI with Tynamo Resteasy for Tapestry 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249777/swagger-ui-with-tynamo-resteasy-for-tapestry-5-4)
to create the `swagger.json`, I'd like to use swagger-ui to expose this json.

Can anyone point me on how to use this dist folder as is in Tapestry (pref. 5.4)?

Note: I tried using the `index.html` as a `tml` (by loading all `@Imports` it needs in the `.java` page corresponding to the `tml`, but that did not work, as a lot of assets referenced inside the `dist` folder give me `404`...Also, seems like there should be an easier way to do this?)